# How do I find the common ancestor to rebase onto?

Tags: git

How do I find what commit a branch *originally* branched from, after the upstream branch has been rebased?

I often need to rebase several related branches when I pull `origin/master`:

```
Before rebasing b1:

O1 - O2 - O3 - O4 - O5 - O6 <=master
       \
        G - H - I <=b1
                 \
                  T - U - V <=b2

After rebasing b1:

O1 - O2 - O3 - O4 - O5 - O6 <=master
       \                   \
        G - H - I           G' - H' - I' <=b1
                 \
                  T - U - V <=b2
```

Rebasing `b1` required a lot of conflict resolutions. To avoid resolving the same conflicts when rebasing `b2`, **how do I find what commit `b2` originally branched from, i.e. `I`?**

---

`rebase` forces me to re-resolve all the original conflicts `Branch1` had:

```
$ git checkout b2
$ git rebase  # crap!
```

To avoid that, I want to do is rebase `b2` *onto the original commit it branched off of*, i.e. `I`. The set of commits I want to apply is `I..b2`, which means I want to use `I` as the **upstream** for `rebase` (even though it's not a branch anymore). Now I have to specify `--onto b1` (otherwise git will apply my changes onto `I`, which is what I already have).

```
git rebase --onto b1 I
```

My question: **How do I find `I`**?

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to. Git can actually figure this out for you using the reflog. Just pass the `--fork-point` flag to `git rebase`, e.g. `git rebase --fork-point b1`.

If you do need to do this manually (e.g. you're using an old version of Git), you can just look through the reflog yourself. Either `git log -g b1` or `git reflog show b1` will show you the reflog for b1, and you can use that to figure out what the last commit was before the rebase.

Comment: That might explain my problem: I use multiple working directories, with the directories in .git symlinked to my "primary" workdir. So the reflogs for the workdir with `b1` checked out and the workdir with `b2` checked out are separate.

If I don't immediately rebase `b2` after rebasing `b1` (or maybe rebase `b1` multiple times before getting around to updating `b2`), it gets harder to manually look through the reflog to find the right commit. I guess I can cross-reference the two reflogs, though, looking for a common commit that isn't in `master`?

Comment: Whichever workdir you used to rebase `b1`, just check the reflog in that dir.